# Create points based on location of known points in a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, 3d-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I'm using ArcGIS 3D Analyst 10.5.0

I have a layer of points, we will call them points1, and I want to create a layer of points2 based on a set distance and direction away from points1. The distance will be a constant, while the direction is data that is included in the attribute table of points1.

Is there is a way in ArcMap to do all of these points at once?

Rather than creating each point using create feature?

I don't know Python, but I do know R and could potentially script this in R if I had a general idea of what commands to use (not much experience with GIS in R).

Comment: Do you know the mathematics of finding the new X, Y? Your features are points you can use the AddXY tool, which adds the current X, Y coordinate to the feature class then add fields for NewX and NewY, if you're not comfortable with field calc export the table to DBF or CSV and open in Excel (or similar) populate the NewX and NewY from the bearings and distance. After you know where the features are located you can then generate a new point event layer or feature class from XY table.. that's only if the existing answer doesn't work out for you, there's a lot of steps and it's easy to get lost.

Comment: This is 1liner expression in field calculator on Shape. arcpy.Point(!shape.firstpoint.x +....). Run it on a copy of original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the ESRI [code sharing](http://codesharing.arcgis.com/) website, you  can bet someone has done something similar and uploaded free to the community, you just need to search for it.

For example I've created a tool called [create line by bearing](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b0c54fe415641e7af8490c4ba7d4bcf) which does most of what you need, it creates the line. You could then use other standard system tools too extract the end point.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Unfortunately, what I was trying to do didn't end up working. I need rectangle polygons that are oriented differently and I was thinking I could buffer the points and then use Feature Envelope to Polygon to create the squares... but I realized that a) I can't create a rectangle using Feature Envelope and b) I can't rotate these squares in the direction I need them. Still learned a lot today, thanks for sharing your code.